# Make Atom change JSX second tag when I edit first

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, jsx

When writing JSX code for a React app using Atom, say I have a view:

```
<View style={styles.container}></View>
```

And I change the first tag to

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}></View>
```

How can I make the second tag automatically change? WebStorm and all JetBrains IDEs support this.

Comment: not an answer, but decent workaround is hitting cmd-d to trigger multiple cursor on closing tag, pretty much will do what you want.

Comment: have you `apm install react` ?

Comment: Yes, just tried that and got an incompatibility error because I already had Facebook-React from Nuclide.